# Error opening pem file in php function openssl_pkcs7_sign

Tags: php, xampp, passbook

I'm trying to sign an iOS passbook in php using PKPass class with Xampp (PHP 5.4.7, OpenSSL 1.0.1c).

The result signature file is empty and the php log shows the message :
"PHP Warning:  openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error opening the file, AWDRCA.pem".

Here is the code I execute :

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(
  $paths['manifest'],
  $paths['signature'],
  $certdata,
  $privkey,
  array(),
  PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED,
  $this->WWDRcertPath
);
```

I have verified all variables in parameters.
My certificates are OK because I have succeeded in generating a passbook with openssl using command line.

Comment: Which one is `AWDRCA.pem`?  certdata or privkey?

Comment: AWDRCA.pem is "$this->WWDRcertPath" (Apple World wide Developer Relations Certification Authority).

Comment: what do you see if you write the contents of WWDRcertPath to the error log `error_log(print_r($this->WWDRcertPath, true), 0);`.  If the file path is correct and the file exists, does PHP have the necessary permissions to read it?

Comment: The file can be open.

[07-Jun-2013 19:21:37 UTC] $this->WWDRcertPath : AWDRCA.pem

[07-Jun-2013 19:21:37 UTC] file_get_contents($this->WWDRcertPath) : -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEI....V1FQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your PHP environment's Openssl extension was too old.
You must designate absolute path as "D:/xampp/www/1.pem".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a comment, not an answer; please don't post it as an answer. (Also, we prefer to resolve issues in comments, rather than by message, so future visitors with the same problem can benefit. {Also, FYI, we don't even have private messaging here.})

Comment: I can not find the button to comment , And I think my answer is right ,it can resolve the problem .

Comment: Firstly, [you need 50 reputation to comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Secondly, it looks (at least to me) like there just isn't enough here to properly answer the question. This is two sentences, one of which starts with *Maybe*, and not a code sample in sight - I think it needs more work to be an answer.